# How to use the particle system for smoke

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snoqEfz0dFU) tutorial to make an animated intro for videos.  I got to about the 30 min. mark in the video, and the goal is to add smoke.  The person who made the tutorial used the particle system for the smoke, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Using the object works, but not the particle system.  I am using a more up to date version of blender so I'm wondering if there is an extra box somewhere I haven't checked or something along those lines.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!  Let me know if any further clarification is needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you turn off the the physics and the type of particle in the particle settings? Or your computer my not be able to handle smoke.